# Datatable - assign css present inside a table cell to other table cells

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I am using [datatables](http://datatables.net) plugin.
My table contains a column name css which contains css for columns in that row.
For ex, table in database is as follows,

```
 Name   Priority   Percent    CSS 
--------------------------------------------------------- 
 abc    high       50         .priority{color:red}    .percent {color:yellow}
 xyz    low        70         .priority{color:green}  .percent {color:green}
 pqr    medium     10         .priority{color:yellow} .percent {color:red}
```

Now while showning the datatable I dont want to include the css column but I want to apply the css on perticular cell.
I am trying to achieve something like below,

```
$('#example').dataTable({              
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {  
         $(row).children().each(function(index, td){
             // perform operation here
         });
    return nRow;
    }
```

I don't understand how to add css for particular `<td>` using css from `<td>` of same row.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Its not tested but might work for you. use this in the doc ready handler.

```
$("td:contains('high')").css({"color":"red"});
$("td:contains('high')").next('td').css({"color":"yellow"});
```

same applicable to other tds too:

```
$("td:contains('low')").css({"color":"green"});
$("td:contains('low')").next('td').css({"color":"green"});
```

and

```
$("td:contains('medium')").css({"color":"yellow"});
$("td:contains('medium')").next('td').css({"color":"red"});
```

Try this if this solves or helps.

Comment: thanks Jai. but the css can be anything I mean it can be `priority{color:red;background-color:#eee;text-decoration:underline;} .percent {color:yellow;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold}`. In my question it was just an example. The css depends on the person who creates the row as there are so many people who can access the same table.